# Understanding cryptography

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, cryptography

Basically, I am trying to study cryptography, and the primary resource that I have is:  [Introduction to Cryptography](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138197017) by **D. R. Stinson**,  So, I barely  made pass the SPN algorithm  described and am  stuck on the very first few pages in the book which describes linear and differential cryptanalysis.

There are a lot of concepts from probability that are not based and I can't start to read the book. So, my question is about resource recommendation, and for anyone  who has learnt cryptography  must had come across this book, if so, what should I study before I learn cryptography to align  my knowledge to the contents of this book, and recommend books that I can use  as a base to understand the above book.

Comment: The link to the book is broken.  Can you add author and book title?

Comment: There are a few online courses on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/courses?query=cryptography&). Take a look at the pre-requisites or maybe take a course. They are free if you just want to learn the material and don't care about a certificate.

Comment: First, please provide an author; title is really common. Second, there's a Wiki about [Substitution-Permutation Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution%E2%80%93permutation_network), though that may not be of much help as it sounds like you're trying to get into the subject. One thing that maybe helpful is there's a _structure_ to information regardless of field; eg. in cryptography key-words like `key`s, `cipher text`... and if you focus first on _categorizing_, it may allow you to _contextualize_ new bits of info and how they fit into the larger whole of some subject.

Comment: @S0AndS0 , I've added the author and  checked the link

Comment: @NazimJ  , I've check the link,I don't know how a broken link got there

Comment: @JohnDouma, I've gone through one entire course present at coursera, provided by Stadford university, and still stinson's book is still not making much sense to me,

Comment: Wow, rounded to the nearest nickel you're investing `~`$0.15$ per-page! No wonder an effort is being made to understand the content... as you're just getting into it I'm going to suggest spending a bit of time with [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography)'s free courses, which'll at the very least get you up to speed with most of the basics and terms that'll be used in scholarly works. The other thing I can suggest for learning is picking up a programming language, that way you can actively build some of the concepts into something that functions too.

Comment: @S0AndS0, I've  checked Khan's syllabus and they're pretty much the same as stadford's  basic introduction to cryptography which I have completed and still  this doesn't serve a good  foundation  to the back I'm mentioning. In particular, I can't get anything in the book done  with combinations, probability and cryptanalysis. Some unusual things like: P[a xor b=0] are done without much explanation, and the derivation of much theorems aren't  explained intuitively

Comment: Nice that Standford doesn't want to be out done by some rando on the YouTubes, $bu^{u}u_{u}t$ [probability using combinations](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/precalculus/prob-comb/prob-combinatorics-precalc/v/probability-using-combinations) is on Khan Academy too. For cryptanalysis; try starting with breaking a Caesar Cipher, eg. _"`nkrru sgzn yzgiq kdingtmk`"_, using frequency analyses; most common letter combos. When breaking that's _no big deal_, try the vulnerabilities discussed for [ECDSA](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) and other algorithms.